# How To Convert Vec<u8> to &str or String in substrate runtime

Tags: substrate

```
   let container_returned_data = container::Module::<T>::check_for_app_name(&app_id,&instruction_name); //container_returned_data is tuple contains (bool,Vec<(Vec<u8>,Vec<u8>)>)
        if container_returned_data.0{
            let d = container_returned_data.1[0].1.clone();
           let data_str:&str = from_utf8(&d).unwrap();
           let data_str2 = data_str.to_string();
           debug::error!(target:"runner","{:?}",&data_str2);
         //  debug::error!(target:"norm","{:?}",&data_str2);
           Self::function_executer(data_str);
            //now implement the ail_v2 function inside this.
            unsafe{
                Self::deposit_event(Event::FunctionsReceived(FUNCTION.clone()));
            }
        }
```

**I have used core::str::from_utf8 but it is not converting the bytes to array**
I have to perform the following steps

```
 let querys_ = query_.replace("\n","").trim().trim_end().to_string();

 let l_data_querys:Vec<&str> = querys_.trim().trim_end().split("<<-").collect();
```

Comment: try &d or d.as_slice() . No String.

Comment: ERROR tokio-runtime-worker runner: "[70, 117, 110, 99, 116, 105, 111, 110, 32, 97, 98, 99, 32, 45, 62, 62, 32, 67, 82, 69, 65, 84, 69, 32, 83, 84, 79, 82, 65, 71, 69, 32, 99, 100, 101, 59, 32, 60, 60, 45, 32, 67, 82, 69, 65, 84, 69, 32, 83, 84, 79, 82, 65, 71, 69, 32, 65, 66, 67, 83, 59]" it is returning me this

Comment: let d1 = d.as_slice();
               let data_str:&str = from_utf8(&d1).unwrap();
              // let data_str2 = data_str.to_string();
               debug::error!(target:"runner","{:?}",data_str); @ClarkLee

Comment: You should not be using String in your runtime, as Strings are not SCALE encoded, you should use Vec<u8> instead. Check https://docs.substrate.io/v3/advanced/scale-codec/ for more info on scale-codec